# Passing parameters to Databricks SQL from SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, odbc, databricks, databricks-sql

I have just set up a connection to connect SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) to my Databricks SQL endpoint. The connection works and I can query data. I am using the Simba Spark ODBC driver to do this and it works just fine.

Now, my report datasets in SSRS need to use some parameters. In regular SQL Server, I would just use `@Parameter` in my query. However, Databricks SQL works different passing parameters and the syntax should be `{{ Parameter }}`. I've tried multiple versions of this, for example `{{ @Parameter }}`, `'{{ Parameter }}'` et cetera.

This is what it looks like in SSRS:

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and it will give me:

```
ERROR [42000] [Simba][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: [PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: [PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '{'(line 3, pos 28)
```

In Databricks SQL itself, this works fine! A parameter box pops up and I can fill it in.

[image]

Now, what DOES work, but is sub-optimal in my opinion, is setting the parameters as '?'

```
SELECT        *
FROM          table
WHERE        column = ?
```

Then I will also need to put a '?' in the parameters section in SSRS, but this way you'll never know which parameter is which (in case of more than 1 parameter). Ofcourse I have tried `?Parameter` and different versions of it... With no luck

Now I'm wondering: Am I doing something wrong, is this simply not possible? I am really starting the assume the latter.

Really appreciate any help or suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any luck with getting this to work?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. We went with Azure Synapse serverless in between. We were also in touch with solution architects from Databricks themselves and  they also told us the integration between Databricks and SSRS is near impossible.

Answer (score 0):

So... I've found a solution for this, though it's a bit janky.

You can define the SQL Query in SSRS using an expression. If you build up your expression something like this, then it will build out a string that includes your parameterised WHERE predicate in the SQL query that gets sent to Databricks:

```
= "SELECT * FROM Table1 t WHERE t.FieldName IN ('" + 
JOIN(Parameters!MyParameterName.Value, "','") +
"')"
```

In this example, I'm passing a multi-value parameter, so I'm joining the parameter selections in to one big string, but if you're filtering by a single select parameter you could make this even simpler.

Comment: ...yes, fully aware that SELECT * is bad, this was just for demonstration purposes